# Spring boot read and new mail Listener on spring-boot-starter-mail

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I want to demonstrate the **email application** using the `spring boot MVC` in that web application I follow [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-email) tutorial I can easily send the emails using spring boot.

**Here my question is**

1. how can I read the emails using spring boot..?
2. how can I listen for new emails and how to update the inbox on the view..?

please suggest me any solutions for that because I searched a lot but I can find only send email example.please share me if you have any **working samples** for that using spring boot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have encountered the same problem. Google for a long time did not find the answer, but fortunately my scene is relatively simple, so I use of the [JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) api to deal with my problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Umang Loriya .I also found this solution but when i am try to do with in the mvc `spring boot` we cannot manage the connection to `smtp` server and also i don't know how to add listener for the new mail

Comment: thanks for the reply @aLeX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider using [Spring integration mail support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound)

There is a [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/spring-integration-java-dsl-reference) for this purposes.
An example of IMAP config could be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/mail/MailTests.java)

The key aspects are like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {
    ...

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow imapIdleFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter("imap://user:pw@localhost:" + imapIdleServer.getPort() + "/INBOX")
                        .autoStartup(true)
                        .searchTermStrategy(this::fromAndNotSeenTerm)
                        .userFlag("testSIUserFlag")
                        .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "false")
                                .put("mail.imap.connectionpoolsize", "5"))
                        .shouldReconnectAutomatically(false)
                        .headerMapper(mailHeaderMapper()))
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("imapIdleChannel"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public HeaderMapper<MimeMessage> mailHeaderMapper() {
        return new DefaultMailHeaderMapper();
    }

    private SearchTerm fromAndNotSeenTerm(Flags supportedFlags, Folder folder) {
        try {
            FromTerm fromTerm = new FromTerm(new InternetAddress("bar@baz"));
            return new AndTerm(fromTerm, new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
        }
        catch (AddressException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @alexfedotov.I try `spring mail integration` also but i con't find any example using annotation based configuration.I am using `spring Boot` Annotation based configuration.

Comment: Added more details to the answer

Comment: @Loga Nathan did you make your code working or got any complete working example for the same ?

Comment: @alexmagnus Above code keeps listening to incoming messages. Now how to read the new emails from another class ?

Comment: @VGH, just handle messages sent to the channel you specified. Another option is to use [service activators](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/spring-integration-java-dsl-reference#serviceactivators-handle)

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.grandview.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.grandview.model.EmailConfig;
import com.grandview.util.MessageParser;

@Service
public class EmailService {
    @Autowired
    private EmailConfig emailConfig;

    Folder emailFolder;
    Store store;
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    @PostConstruct
    void setup() {
        String server = emailConfig.getHost();
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", server);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", emailConfig.getPort());
        //properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        Store store = null;
        try {
            store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
            store.connect(server, emailConfig.getUsername(), emailConfig.getPassword());
            emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    synchronized void read() throws MessagingException, IOException {
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            System.out.println(MessageParser.getMessageBody(message));
        }
        emailFolder.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about how to receive emails based on Spring Boot and a Java library for mail-receiving (e.g Subetha SMTP), you can check [Receive emails with SubEtha SMTP and Spring Boot](https://redamessoudi.com/receive-emails-with-subetha-springboot/)

Comment: For the complete details please follow my github account the link bellow: https://github.com/sushantrout/read-email-by-spring-boot/tree/main

Answer (score 0):

Sharing another solution with a working example:

Read incoming emails with JavaMail API, IMAP protocol and IMAP IDLE feature.

1. Use JavaMail API for IMAP connection which provides implementation for IMAP.
2. For monitoring we need IMAP IDLE feature, which allows our application to receive immediate notifications when new messages arrive in the mailbox, rather than relying on periodic polling.

Refer detailed implementation of this here: https://medium.com/@sushant7/how-to-monitor-incoming-emails-in-a-spring-boot-application-indefinitely-7dabbdb74b2d